# API for Event Registration with Custom Fields?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, api, registration

I am trying to register event participants from code. I have created a custom field group for "Participants".

Using the API, how can I create a value for the custom fields and have them associated with the event that a contact is registered for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I just figured it out. I just need to chain the API call with CustomValue create:

```
CRM.api3('Participant', 'create', {
  "debug": 1,
  "sequential": 1,
  "event_id": 145,
  "contact_id": 2,
  "role_id": "Attendee",
  "api.CustomValue.create": {"custom_223":3}
}).done(function(result) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: More simply, just add ``"custom_223": 3``  The API explorer can help with the syntax and with figuring out which custom_N you need

Comment: HI could anyone let me know step by step api developement guide.